# Display error message if same record exist with combination of some fields?

Tags: validation-rule, duplicate-management

I have taken three fields from case object called `AccountName`, `IntegrationTo__c` and `SfType__c` (checkbox).

I have created one case record with a specific combination of three fields.

For the second time I create a record with that combination, then 
display error message only if SfType__c is true in first record otherwise allow 
for record creation.

```
trigger AvoidDuplicate on Case(before insert)

{    

    set<string> newNameSet = new set<string>();
    newNameSet = new set<string>();

    set<string> newEmailSet = new set<string>();

    set<string> dbNameSet = new set<string>();

    set<string> dbEmailSet = new set<string>();

    for(Case newLead : trigger.new){

        newNameSet.add(newLead.Account.Name);

        newEmailSet.add(newLead.IntegrationTo__c);

    }

    for(Case dbLead : [select id, Case.Account.Name, IntegrationTo__c from Case where IntegrationTo__c IN: newEmailSet OR Case.Account.Name IN: newNameSet]){

        dbNameSet.add(dbLead.Account.Name);

        dbEmailSet.add(dbLead.IntegrationTo__c);

    }

    for(Case newLead : trigger.new){

        if(dbNameSet.contains(newLead.Account.Name) && dbEmailSet.Contains(newLead.IntegrationTo__c))

            newLead.addError('You are inserting Duplicate Case');

    }

}
```

i wrote this this not checking the account field name and integration__c values only with combination of account and integration__c shows error

Answer (score 2):

you don't need a trigger to achieve this.

1. create a text field and mark it as unique
2. do a workflow / process with a field update action on Case creation to update this text field with the combined value of the 3 fields.
3. then the next time you try to insert another case with the same combination in those 3 fields, the unique constraint on the field will automatically prevent it.

---

UPDATE - an example formula for your field update to combine the 3 fields could be simply concatenating them

```
Account.Name & IntegrationTo__c  & IF(SfType__c, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```

like @Adrian mentioned, this will work when all 3 fields are mandatory / required and will have values all the time.

if any of the fields can be blank, then you need to consider expanding the formula with null checks and inserting default values in case of blanks, etc..

Comment: One concern might be how null fields interact with this solution. It should still be compatible, whatever requirements dictate, but may require a bit of extra care.

Comment: ye, the formula we use to combine the 3 values into the single unique field need to cover those edge cases.

Comment: @vamsi thanks for reply suggest any example for reference

Comment: @Vamsi suggest any formula on that text field

Comment: @Vamsi three fields are not mandatory fields as i'm using your formula but this will allow duplicate record creation.please update the formula account have cases as related list one account has only one combination of case record allows with above three fields only if sttype uncheck if sftype is checkd don't allow for duplicates

Answer (score 0):

@Siva:It will check once

```
trigger CaseDuplicateAcc on Case (before insert, before update) {

 List<case> caselist = [select id,accountid,integration__c,account.name,Check__c from case];

  for(case c:Trigger.new)
  {
    for(case cc: Caselist)
    {
      if(c.Check__c == false)
      {
      if(c.account.name==cc.account.name || c.integration__c == cc.integration__c)
      {   
         c.adderror('Already exist same account name and integration in case object');
      }
      }
    }
  }

}
```